# Solr query - URL too long when I request for search with large number of facet

Tags: url, solrnet, solr6

I'm using solr-6.4.2 version and I've large number of facet fields.
When I request for query, it's log in Solr Log file with "URL to long" and not returning any item result.

I'm using SolrNet and it send get request.
I'm not getting solr query in SolrLog file, but there is large number of data passing in Solr.

Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your solr core folder

Edit your core's solrconfig.xml file.
Solr\cores\YOURCORENAME\conf\solrconfig.xml

Now go to select requestHandler 
and add line

```
<int name="facet.limit">-1</int>
```

If this line exist and have any value then change it to -1

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <int name="start">0</int>
          <int name="rows">10</int>
          <str name="wt">json</str>
          <int name="indent">2</int>
          <str name="defType">edismax</str>
          <int name="facet.limit">-1</int>
          ... ... ...
          ... ... ...
          ... ... ...

 </requestHandler>
```

This is helped me.